# GpsTracker : GoogleApiClient Wifi and mobile data getting latitude and longitude not working?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I am developing GpsTracker application currently am getting lat,lng value using gps, once i off the gps i am not able to get any lat,lng value but my requirement is mobile data or wifi or gps based on the availability i need to get lat, lng value i know very well using location manager but it's consume more battery compare to googleapi client so i used googleapi client - fusedlocationproviderapi please guide me why its not working in this functionality in current api.

```
public class UpdateLocation extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;

    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateLocationService";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO do something useful
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createLocationRequest();
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(UpdateLocation.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(UpdateLocation.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(UpdateLocation.this).build();
        mLocationClient.connect();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() +", "+ mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mLocationClient, this);
        }
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: When did Location manager deprecated? I heard only LocationClient has been deprecated.

Comment: When you turn off gps, are you setting location mode to off? You will need to set location mode to battery saving mode to test network location only.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar yeah you are correct...:thanks

Comment: is it possible to get lat and lng value using google api client using wifi/mobile data?@MadhukarHebbar

Comment: @balaji I think you should not off GPS Completely; If you are requesting location updates then you need to call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);` inorder to get last known location from provider.